# React setState is not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, slider, state

I am creating a slider using ReactJS.

I used `componentDidMount()` to start slider from slide 0, every 2 seconds (Using `setInterval()` function). It works fine by changing slide number via `setState()` method.

I have created two buttons to force slider to move left or right by clicking on. Also, I have written a method for `onClick()` to increase or decrease the slide number.

Once, I have clicked on one of them, it works fine, and the state changes successfully. However, this rendering will be reset to previous state before clicking!

For an example, if I am in slide 2 and hit on left button I should expect slide 1 is shown and it is Ok. However, after 2 seconds it returns to slide 3 instead of 2.

What's wrong with this?

```
state = {
  activeSlideNumber: 0,
}

//Total Number of items is 5

sliderLeft = () => {
  let leftnumber = 0
  let newActiveSlideNumber = this.state.activeSlideNumber
  newActiveSlideNumber === 0 ? leftnumber = 4 :  leftnumber = newActiveSlideNumber - 1 
  this.setState({
    activeSlideNumber: leftnumber
  })
}

componentDidMount() {
  let newActiveSlideNumber = this.state.activeSlideNumber
  setInterval(() => {
    newActiveSlideNumber === 4 ? newActiveSlideNumber = 0 : newActiveSlideNumber++
    this.setState({
      activeSlideNumber: newActiveSlideNumber
    })
  }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: I posted some code

Comment: @Xman2018 Edited the code.

Comment: This code was edited

Comment: Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only when the component gets mounted, ***newActiveSlideNumber*** is taking the value from the state. After every 2 sec its not taking the updated value from the state because the statement ***let newActiveSlideNumber = this.state.activeSlideNumber*** is outside the ***setinterval*** function.